# Transaction Rooms APIs

Tags: docusignapi, dtr

I am trying to call transaction rooms APIs.
I have followed all steps related to generating a token and i am sure 100% that 
I have a correct token and refresh token.
This token which I use for cartavi APIs rooms and other endpoints but I always get Unauthorized access token.
Does anyone have the same issue?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would have given wrong scopes in the intitial OAUTH url call. DTR has different scopes and the scope(s) which is present on the DS ESign API docs will not work to call DTR APIs.